# How to display the total price from class in driver?

Tags: java, class, methods

Need to create a pizza parlor using java classes. I have already created a class and driver. Everything is working good, but I don't really understand how to display the total price and all other details of pizza that the user has ordered.

```
//Pizza class
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Pizza {

    private String crust;
    private boolean extraCheese;
    private boolean drink;
    private double price;
    private String [] toppings = new String[5];


    public Pizza() {//constructor

        this.crust = "Regular Crust";
        this.extraCheese = false;
        this.drink = false;
        this.price = 6.99;

    }

    public void setCrust(String crust) {//setter

        this.crust = crust;

    }

    public void setExtraCheese(boolean extraCheese) {//setter

        this.extraCheese = extraCheese;

    }

    public void setDrink(boolean drink) {//setter

        this.drink = drink;

    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {//setter

        this.price = price;

    }

    public String getCrust() {//getter

        return this.crust;

    } 

    public boolean getExtraCheese() {//getter

        return this.extraCheese;
    }

    public boolean getDrink () {//getter

        return this.drink;

    }


    public void selectCrust() {

        crust = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of crust do you want? \nOriginal \nThin \nCheese Stuffed \nDeep Dish \nPlease, type a full name of crust.");

    }

    public void addExtraCheese(String decision) {

        if(decision.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {

            extraCheese = true;
            price = price+0.30;
            price = total1;

        }

    }

    public void addDrink (String decision) {

        if(decision.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {

            drink = true;
            price = price+1.39;
        }

    }

    public void addToppings() {

        String [] toppingsList  = {"Pepperoni", "Onions", "Mushrooms", "Pepper", "Sausage"};
        String Answ;
        String Total = "";
        double price  = 0;
        int index = 0;
        do {
            String temp = "";
            toppings[index] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please, select toppings from the list: \nEnter the number \n1) "+ toppingsList[0] +"\n2) "+ toppingsList[1] +"\n3) "+ toppingsList[2] +"\n4) "+toppingsList[3]+"\n5) "+toppingsList[4]);

            if (toppings[index].equals("1")) {
                temp = temp + toppingsList[0] + ", ";
                price = price+0.20;
            }       
            if (toppings[index].equals("2")) {
                temp = temp + toppingsList[1] + ", ";
                price = price+0.20;
            }   
            if (toppings[index].equals("3")) {          
                temp = temp + toppingsList[2] + ", ";
                price = price+0.20;
            }   
            if (toppings[index].equals("4")) {          
                temp = temp + toppingsList[3] + ", ";
                price = price+0.20;
            }
            if (toppings[index].equals("5")) {
                temp = temp + toppingsList[4] + ", ";
                price = price+0.20;
            }
            index++;
            Total = Total+temp; 
            Answ = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to add one more topping? \nYes/No");//asks if the user wants to select one more service
            } while (Answ.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") );

        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Chosen Toppings are: "+Total+" - $%.2f",price));
        public double getPrice() {//getter

        return this.price ;
    }
    }

}
```

Driver

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Driver {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Pizza NotRegular = new Pizza();


        double price;
        double TotalPrice;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to our Pizza Parlor!");
        NotRegular.selectCrust();
        String decision = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to add extra cheese?");
        NotRegular.addExtraCheese(decision);
        String decision1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to add drink?");
        NotRegular.addDrink(decision1);
        NotRegular.addToppings();


    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help users answer your question better, please include more details as to the specific problem you are trying to solve. How do you intend to display this information?

Comment: Also, have you considered using [`JOptionPane#showConfirmDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-)? It might serve your purposes better than `showInputDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        ... // Your previous code
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Price: " + NotRegular.getPrice() + "  Crust: " + NotRegular.getCrust());

    }
}
```

This will print an option pane showing price and cruts. Use similar way to get any other thing. Basically, you want to invoke/call getter methods (methods that return properties and that have comments `//getters` in front of them).

Also, you can read more about `getters` and `setters` [here](http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/get-and-set-methods).

Comment: thank you, it is definitely working, but not with NotRegular.getPrice(). It displays the original cost of pizza, which is 6.99 without drink and any toppings. I need to display the final price with drink, extra cheese all toppings that the user might choose.

Comment: Thats the problem with methods you call earlier (the `selectCheese`, `selectCrust` etc). They may not be adding their value to total price correctly. Please learn how to debug the code, its one of the most useful tools at such problems.